# Can't get bootable usb to show up in bios

Tags: boot, 18.04, live-usb

I have a Dell xps 13 (9370) and I'm trying to fresh install Ubuntu 18.  Didn't know that developer edition existed.  But I can't get the usb to show up in the bios.  I know that I partitioned it properly, but I can't figure out why it isn't showing up or being recognized at all.

Comment: Make sure you have followed your computers steps to boot from usb, and did yours come pre-installed with Ubuntu Xenial?

Comment: No, I got mine with windows.  Didn't know you could get it preinstalled with ubuntu.  And it simply just doesn't recognize that the usb is there I think.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from Dell. How did you create USB flash drive installer? UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: Just updated the bios and didn't help.  I formatted it with RUFUS like they guide says.  Formatted as GPD and NTFS cause that's how all the other partitions on my computer are set.

Comment: Did you try enabling Thunderbolt boot support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to: [New XPS 13 (9370) USB Port question](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/New-XPS-13-9370-USB-Port-question/td-p/6048300)

Your laptop will only boot a live USB plugged into the right hand port.

> The ports on the left support Thunderbolt 3; the port on the right
>   does not.  As a result, the left-hand ports may be disabled at boot
>   time unless you enable Thunderbolt boot support in the BIOS.  I would
>   have thought that option would only affect devices that actually try
>   to communicate over the Thunderbolt protocol, but recent threads have
>   indicated that this option also affects whether regular USB-type
>   devices connected to those ports are visible at boot time.

Comment: **I CAN'T BELIEVE THIS WAS THE ISSUE**

Thank you my friend.  Now I gotta figure out what to do now that it's booting to grub XD

Answer (score 0):

Disbale the secure boot in BIOS and change the boot mode to legecy. You will these options in BIOS->BOOT tab.
After changing the setting restart your system and go in boot menu. You will find your usb option there.

Comment: Nope, didn't show up after setting it to legacy.

Comment: Have you check if the usb is bootable?

Comment: It works on my old hp (runs into GNU GRUB boot error), but still is the first thing when I changed the boot order.

Comment: Try changing the boot priority and set usb at first and then hdd/ssd at second

Comment: You still want to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode, since Windows is UEFI.

Comment: Is boot priority Legacy or UEFI??  When I boot to UEFI it allows me to add a path for a new file to open, but I really don't know how find my usb through that.  Legacy allows me to change the boot order, but at the same time when I try and load even windows from that I get a blue screen.